# Accessing one Node Server from another

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have 2 node servers running on different ports on a dedicated server on the web.

Is it possible to access one server (Websocket) from another server (Express.js being accessed via HTTP externally) via the localhost of the dedicated server? (As opposed to accessing the Websocket server from the users own machine from the HTML/Javascript served up by Express)?

Trying to reduce the latency for a single (broadcasting) client.

Comment: Why not run the websocket server in the same process as the Express app?

Comment: Yes of course it is possible, you can contact it like any other server. Have you tried it?

Comment: @robertklep scaling, although premature optimization you *should* keep the web socket separate from the express app (in terms of process) so you can scale the websocket up independently of the webserver

Answer (score 0):

sYou can use [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) on server with express, in order to proxy trafik to WebSockets server.
Bear in mind, that WebSockets due to security reasons should come from the same domain and port (it will not allow Cross-Domain from most browsers).
Another option is to have WebSockets server to serve small iframe, that will have JS that will communicate with parent document using PostMessage. This way is less recommended as is just a workaround and will require much more effort to make it stable.